# Good bounds on partial sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I have an expression of the form $\sum_{j=0}^{k/12}{k \choose j}$. In general, the upper limit of the sum is some fraction of $k$. I am looking for a decent lower bound on this. I know the trivial one is just $k \choose k/12$, but wondering if there is something a bit better than this.